# Using Cake PHP Sort to sort Array Keys

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How do I sort Array keys in PHP with Cake?

```
Array
(
    [2] => h
    [5] => e
    [3] => u
    [1] => w
    [6] => r
    [9] => k
)
```

To

```
Array
(
    [1] => w
    [2] => h
    [3] => u
    [5] => e
    [6] => r
    [9] => k
)
```

Is it possible to use the `Set::sort ($data, $path, $dir)` cake function for this desired result?

Comment: Never mind that CakePHP *is* PHP, right?  It's like those people who are like "i know how to do it in Ruby, but...in RAILS?"  or "how do i do this in jQuery?  No Javascript solutions please...".

Comment: Why this question have downvoted 4 times within a day, where the question had asked before 4 months?

Comment: Cause someone edited it, bumping it back to the front page, i imagine.  Or cause it was mentioned in PHP chat.  :)

Comment: What you mean by PHP chat here?

Comment: SO has [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).  One of them is the [PHP room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php).  Sometimes questions get linked to in there, and if the question has problems, it'll end up collecting downvotes (or even close/delete votes) from people who want to "clean up" the PHP tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot sort an simple array by his key in cake. You can only sort like this: (or you can use {n}.{n} )

```
 $array = (e,h,u,w,r);
 $result = Set::sort($array, '{n}', 'asc');
 pr($result);
```

For key sorting use ksort php function, or create in cake a ksort function with same properties and use it

```
ksort( $array );
foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
print "$key = $val<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Can't you use the [php ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) function?

```
ksort($array);
```

Comment: I totally agree: Set::sort() was not invented for basic sort functionality...^^